# Create a batch file with multiple options like SQLCMD

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem when i write a program that use batch script.
I need a program that get more than 1 value from user.
This program like `"sqlcmd -s servername -d database"` will get 2 values (server-name, database).

Thanks

Comment: show us your batch script and tell  us, what your problem is.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: Does it have to be batch?  This is trivial in PowerShell, VBScript, or most languages invented in the last three decades.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use positional arguments %1-%9.  This will allow your user to pass things on the command-line in a known order.

In your example, if you need servername and database on the command-line, you can specify that the servername will be the first argument and the database will be the second argument.  So, your batch command would be like:

batchcmd servername database

The batch file would look like:

```
SETLOCAL
set servername=%1
set databasename=%2
...
```

You can reference up to 9 arguments %1-%9 by number based on their position on the command-line.